# jquery localstorage not working on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to use localStorage in jQuery to remember active menu item. But it doesn't seem to work.

**This is menu -**

```
<ul class="mainnav ">
   <li class="active" title="Ranger Dashboard" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><a
                                    href="/Home/Index"></a></li>
   <li rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Upload a Funcard"><a href="#"></a></li>

   </ul>
```

**jQuery-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.mainnav li').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var activeIndex = $(this).index();
            localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', activeIndex);
        });
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        var activeIndex = localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue');
        $('.mainnav> li:eq("' + activeIndex + '")').addClass('active');

    });

</script>
```

What went wrong with this jQuery code? Please help.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, Didn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making sure that you're resetting all the menu items on `window.load`?:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $('.mainnav li').removeClass('active');
  // etc
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/MjVxu/).

Answer (score 0):

The quotes surround the literal string parts of the selector, which is then joined to the variable with the plus sign.

```
  $('.mainnav> li:eq(' + activeIndex + ')').addClass('active');
```